# Is electric field like a dimension of space?

Tags: electric-fields, spacetime-dimensions

We all know the classical four-dimensions used to locate objects in space:  Length, width, height and time.  It occurred to me that electric field acts also like a kind of dimension does it not?  Every point in space corresponds to a vector with a certain magnitude and direction.

Comment: Also the magnetic field. It is better to express both together as the vector potential $\mathbf A(t,x,y,z)$. But I don't know if it can be called dimensions. It is a vector field, that changes from frame to frame according to Lorentz transformations.

Comment: The other dimensions also change depending on reference frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The definition of the dimension of a physical space is, informally speaking, the degrees of freedom a particle placed within has to move around. Introducing an electric field does not add more degrees of freedom; it simply associates a vector with each point of space. Assigning vectors on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example, does not allow a particle to move above the plane; one has simply associated vectors with points, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

> We all know the classical four-dimensions used to locate objects in
> space: Length, width, height and time.

What you're getting at here is called [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime). The terms "length", "width" and "height" generally refer to a separation between two points in 3-dimensional space rather than being used to label a point in space or spacetime.

> It occurred to me that electric field acts also like a kind of dimension does it not? Every point in space corresponds to a vector with a certain magnitude and direction.

It's a bit hard to tell what you mean here, it sounds like you might be confusing a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field), which is a space in which a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) is assigned to every distinct point, and the axes we use to label points in space or spacetime.